# My xpath query is not returning any results

Tags: php, domxpath

I am trying to scrape some data from Yahoo, but the xpath query is returning me length 0 when I `var_dump` this. Here's a portion of my scraping code.

```
error_reporting(0);

function curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);

    return curl_exec($curl);
}

$page = curl('https://www.yahoo.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$link = $xpath->query('//li[@style="background-color:#fafaff;"]/div/div/div/h3/a');
foreach ($link as $links) {
    $get_title[] = $links->nodeValue;
    $get_link[] = $links->getAttribute('href');
}
```

This code has no syntax errors, but there is a logical error.

Comment: Remove error reportin 0, where is your output? What do u output and not see? You dont have any echos or prints, how do u know its not working

Comment: stealing ads, where there's a first

Comment: its again not working .. i remove error reporting 0

Comment: Dagon do you have solution then tell me please ??

Comment: I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For us to best help you, we need to know what you want your code to do, and you need to provide us with the smallest possible portion of code that doesn't work the way it ought to. Simply dumping a large PHP file on SO and saying "this doesn't work, tell me why" is very unlikely to get you an answer.

Comment: My Mistake i am sorry .

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut kindly tell me now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. The problem is that the HTML returned by Yahoo.com simply doesn't contain any li elements that match your selector. You can see this by looking at the contents of $page.

Comment: Thanks For Your answer . Whats the solution of this bug ? in your opinion ?

Comment: so now what can i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

I check each n every thing . but at last i found another solution . this code is not working . so it’s rubbish . Thanks . The Exact way to scrape data from yahoo is so simple . Using Ajax you can easily scrape data . first load yahoo page and then with the help of ajax scrape anything .
Thanks To all who respond on my question .